# Passing Javascript String to PHP output

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I'm using this web service that prints out table using Javascript functions. I need the table to print out in plain html. This could be done if the Javascript string was transferred to a PHP file. So basically, this is similar to AJAX, but it is in reverse.

Comment: Your question needs more details. Your description of what you want is too sketchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that with ajax also

```
var value = 'This is a test';
if ($(value).val() != 0) {
$.post("jquery2php.php", {
    variable:value
}, function(data) {
    if (data != "") {
        alert('We sent Jquery string to PHP : ' + data);
    }
});
}
```

Important thing here is we are using **$.post**, so we are can gather the information with **$_POST**

We are sending only 1 value, named **variable**.

PHP part;

```
<?php 
$jqueryVariable = $_POST['variable'];
echo $jqueryVariable;
?>
```

I believe, this is the most elegant way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I actually need the table printed out in plain HTML so it can be viewed in the page source. The table is generated using a Javascript function from an external website. Ideally, the solution would involve a PHP file that does not use $_POST variables but could somehow obtain the Javascript's function's return value to output to clean html.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You can still do it. Instead of $.post (you can still use it), use $.get and don't pass any variables or just use load(). When the data will return from jquery2php.php you can display it anywhere you want in the page. Since it is dynamically added content, you can't view it in source code. You can view the source code with extensions like FireBug. Simply append returned data to any div element as html(data) to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily reverse, You could pass the string as a URL variable (www.yoursite.com/?string=yourvariable) and have PHP process it from there.

Comment: this is not an answer as much as it is a qustion

Comment: I think that if a question can be answered with a question that leads the OP down the right path, it can be a better route to enlightenment. That said, I have changed it to please the StackOverlords

Answer (score 0):

I've quoted a ugly method down here But i dont recommend this..

Instead store values in hidden fields in forms and access them through js or do something else..

```
<?php    
echo "<script type=text/javascript>var x = $value; </script>";    
?>
```

then use the variable x in js..

Anyway if you explain ur situation a bit clearer, we can give u best alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is use jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load in the php's html results into the page

in the docs i've linked above they give this example

```
<script>
$("#success").load("/not-here.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
  </script>
```

**EDIT**

in response to your comment on Pixeler's post. You will not be able to just view the source of a ajax based solution. if your ultimate goal is to be able to read the source you have basically three options

1. send them to a new page
2. load in an iframe
3. do it the way you have, use fire fox and [web devloper addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) which will allow you to view generated source. (or something similar)

I'm not sure why there is a need to see the source users don't really care about the source typically the developer uses that